# WPF How to create, save and load multiple setting files

Tags: wpf, settings, config

In my WPF application I have settings accessed by Properties.Settings.Default.Something.
In these user settings I'm saving different textbox, radiobutton, checkbox values.
I need to have sets of these settings depending on one combobox choice, and saved it. For example, user picks "1" in combobox, sets text in textbox, picks 2, sets text in textbox again. After reopening application I want those textbox values saved. Content of combobox options is generated dynamically.

I know those settings are saved in config file located in Users/appdata/... but I have no clue how and if its even possible to make multiple files like this to be manually saved and loaded on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize them as xml-file. Here is an generic example how to do this.
Please check out `DataContract` [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anup1252000/basics-of-datacontract/)

C#

```
 private static T ReadXmlFile<T>(string path) where T : class
    {

        T result = null;
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {

                try
                {
                    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
                    {
                        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                        result = (T)serializer.ReadObject(reader);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex; // or what ever
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

    private static void WriteXmlFile<T>(string path, T content2write) where T : class
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
        }


        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(path,
                                                   new XmlWriterSettings
                                                   {
                                                       Indent = true,
                                                       IndentChars = "  ",
                                                       Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                                                       CloseOutput = true
                                                   }))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, content2write);
        }
    }
```

Maybe save them in your own `AppData`-folder with `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` ;-) and go like this

```
private static readonly string MyPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), @"MyApp\AppDescription");
```